# Find the range of $a$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, even-and-odd-functions

If the function $$f(x)=[4.8+a\sin x]$$ where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function, is an even function then find the range of $a$.

So, if the function of even then $f(-x)= f(x)$.

Therefore,$$[4.8+a\sin x]=[4.8-a\sin x]$$ $$\implies [0.8+a\sin x]=[0.8-a\sin x]$$
But I don't have any idea what to do next, please help.
Cheers

Comment: The answer is $|a| \leq \frac 1 2$.

Comment: If $|a|<.2$ the $f(x)=4$ is constant.  If $a\sin x_0 >.2$ ever then $f (x_0)\ge 5$ while $f (-x)\le 4$.

Answer (score 2):

We want that
$$\lfloor 0.8+a y\rfloor=\lfloor 0.8-a y\rfloor\quad(-1\leq y\leq 1)\ .$$
If $|a|<0.2$ then
$$\lfloor 0.8+a y\rfloor=\lfloor 0.8-a y\rfloor=0\quad(-1\leq y\leq 1)\ .$$
On the other hand, if $|a|\geq0.2$, choose $y:={\displaystyle{0.2\over a}}\in[{-1},1]$
and obtain
$$\lfloor 0.8+a y\rfloor=1,\qquad \lfloor 0.8-a y\rfloor=0\ .$$
It follows that the admissible range for $a$ in this problem is $\>]{-0.2}, 0.2[\>$.